# How can I do NSAttributed words bold in Swift?

Tags: html, swift, xcode, encode

I have the following style of text:

`let text = "Hello <b>World</b>"`

I want to make "World" bold with "b and /b" parameters. The following codes didn't help me:

```
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
    var htmlToString: String {
        return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
    }
}
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The data type String does not have any Meta-Data that formats text-style or font. The NSAttributedString however, does contain such information. What you want to do, is to use the NSAttributedString and assign it to the TextView or whatever you want to display it with.